# want to find out all the financial year list between two dates in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as given below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `loc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `orderdate` date NOT NULL,
  `cash` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `order` (`id`, `loc_id`, `orderdate`, `cash`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2012-02-09', 120),
(2, 2, '2011-07-21', 100),
(3, 3, '2005-04-25', 180),
(4, 1, '2008-12-01', 300),
(5, 2, '2014-07-21', 100),
(6, 3, '2004-04-25', 180),
(7, 1, '1998-12-01', 300);
```

other one is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `location` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `loc_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `location` (`id`, `loc_name`) VALUES
(1, 'region1'),
(2, 'region2'),
(3, 'region3');
```

I want to find out all the sum of cash for all the regions financial year wise.

So my select statement is like:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(a.orderdate) <4 THEN CONCAT(YEAR(a.orderdate)-1,'-',YEAR(a.orderdate))
    ELSE
        CONCAT(YEAR(a.orderdate),'-',YEAR(a.orderdate)+1) END AS Fiscalyear,
SUM(a.cash),b.loc_name
FROM order as a JOIN location b on a.loc_id=b.id
WHERE YEAR(a.orderdate) BETWEEN 2005 AND 2012
GROUP BY Fiscalyear,a.loc_id
```

Its output is :

```
Fiscalyear  | SUM(a.cash)   | loc_name  
2005-2006        |180           | region3    
2008-2009        |300           | region1    
2011-2012        |120           | region1    
2011-2012        |100           | region2
```

BUT i need actually:

```
Fiscalyear  | SUM(a.cash)   | loc_name
2005-2006        |0             | region1    
2005-2006        |0             | region2     
2005-2006        |180           | region3    
2006-2007        |0             | region1 
2006-2007        |0             | region2       
2006-2007        |0             | region3    
2007-2008        |0             | region1    
2007-2008        |0             | region2       
2007-2008        |0             | region3    
2008-2009        |300           | region1    
2008-2009        |0             | region2    
2008-2009        |0             | region3    
2009-2010        |0             | region1    
2009-2010        |0             | region2    
2009-2010        |0             | region3    
2010-2011        |0             | region1  
2010-2011        |0             | region2    
2010-2011        |0             | region3   
2011-2012        |120           | region1    
2011-2012        |100           | region2   
2011-2012        |0             | region3
```

Can you please help me for the single query.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't call a table `order` - not even just for fun

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to list all fiscal years and regions whether or not there are orders for them. One approach is to use a table which lists all fiscal years, like this (I don't use MySQL, but this is how it's done with standard SQL):

```
create table fiscal_years (
    year_name text not null,
    year_start date not null,
    year_end date not null,
    constraint years_pk primary key (year_start, year_end)
);
```

You populate this table with all the years you want:

```
insert into fiscal_years (year_name, year_start, year_end)
values ('2007-2008', '2007-03-05', 2008-03-04');
-- (etc)
```

You can then `CROSS JOIN` this with regions to get all possible combinations of year and region, and then `LEFT JOIN` them with the orders table:

```
SELECT y.year_name, y.loc_name,
    COALESCE(sum (o.cash), 0) as cash_total
FROM (
  SELECT year_start, year_end, year_name,
  location.id as loc_id, loc_name
  FROM fiscal_years
  CROSS JOIN location
) y
LEFT JOIN orders o ON (
    y.year_start < o.orderdate
    and y.year_end >= o.orderdate
    and o.loc_id = y.loc_id
)
GROUP BY y.year_name, y.loc_name
ORDER BY y.year_name, y.loc_name;
```

`LEFT JOIN` returns all rows on the left side of the join (in this case the Cartesian product of `fiscal_years` and `location`) whether or not there are matching rows on the right side (`orders`), so you'll always get all years and all locations listed. If there is no matching row from the right side then `NULL` is returned for all columns on the right, hence the use of `COALESCE()` to return zero instead.

By the way, you shouldn't use reserved words like `order` as table names - even if it doesn't cause a syntax error, it can give rise to confusion at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

#### SQL:

`WHERE date_field >= '2018-04-01 00:00:00' AND date_field < '2018-04-01 00:00:00'`

#### To make it generic, we need to conditionally change Year based on current month

```
WHERE date_field >= (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)>= 4 THEN concat(
            YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), 
            '-04-01 00:00:00'
        ) ELSE concat(
            YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1, 
            '-04-01 00:00:00'
        ) END
) 
AND date_field < (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)>= 4 THEN concat(
            YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)+ 1, 
            '-04-01 00:00:00'
        ) ELSE concat(
            YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), 
            '-04-01 00:00:00'
        ) END
)
```